# how can i count the available user in specific loaction radius with geofire query?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

right now m using **dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount** but it only counts the node available in a child.

here is my code

```
 GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref.child("Userlocation"));
    GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), Raius);

    geoQuery.addGeoQueryDataEventListener(new GeoQueryDataEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataEntered(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, GeoLocation location) {


            int userCounter = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            ads5_userCounter.setText(userCounter + "");


        }

        @Override
        public void onDataExited(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDataMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, GeoLocation location) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDataChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, GeoLocation location) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

this method is not counting all the user avilable at this location radius. please help.

Comment: Hi sam, can you explain more about your problem? for example you can share your firebase structure and show what exactly you need to get from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onDataEntered` method is called for each node that is within the range. Once `onDataEntered` has been called for all nodes that are initially in range, the `onGeoQueryReady` method is called. That means that you can increment a counter in `onDataEntered` and then show it in `onGeoQueryReady`.

```
long count = 0;
geoQuery.addGeoQueryDataEventListener(new GeoQueryDataEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataEntered(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, GeoLocation location) {
    count++;
  }
  @Override
  public void onDataExited(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { }
  @Override
  public void onDataMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, GeoLocation location) { }
  @Override
  public void onDataChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, GeoLocation location) { }

  @Override
  public void onGeoQueryReady() {
    ads5_userCounter.setText(""+count);
  }

  @Override
  public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
    throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you frank, i was thinkiing about that but if was looking for direct method. but thanks again.